# Can this external injection into a set from its power set, be not isomorphic on membership?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, new-foundations

Add a primitive partial unary function symbol $F$ to the first order language of set theory.

Working in Zermelo (Separation restricted to the language of set theory), add the following axioms:

**$F$ function:** $\exists X ( F: \mathcal P(X) \longrightarrow X, F \text { is  injective} )$

**Forward copying:**$ \forall A \exists B: B = \{ \{ F(n)| n \in m \}| m \in A \} $

**Backward copying:** $ \forall A \exists B: B = \{ \{ n| F(n) \in m \}| m \in A \} $

Note: It needs to be emphasized that $F$ is an external function, and that it cannot be used in instances of separation. The proof that such an injective $F$ can exist can be seen from Boffa model construction for NFU. See [here page 5](https://randall-holmes.github.io/Papers/preserves4.pdf), only restrict the automorphism $j$ to $V_{\alpha +1}$, and you get our $F$ where $V_\alpha$ would witness $X$ here.

Now if the graph of $F$ happens to be an *isomorphism on $\in$* [between $dom(F)$ and $Range(F)$], then $F$ cannot be bijective! Since the parity of the set of all ordinals in $\mathcal P(X)$ is different from that in $X$. Hence the following questions:

> Is there an example of $F$ whose graph is not an isomorphism on $\in$ between its domain and range?

> If so, then is it the case that the qualifications of $F$ in the above system are still enough as to forbid $F$ from being a bijection?

The rationale beyond the above question is that if there is no *clear* argument against $F$ being bijective, then this might entail opening the door for a possible proof of $\sf Con(NF)$, as $F$ being bijective would easily interpret a [finite axiomatization of $\sf NF$](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2009/2009.03185.pdf). The interpretation is over $\mathcal P^{-1} (dom(F))$ using a new membership relation $\in^F$ defined as: $$ y \in^F x \iff y \in F^{-1}(x)$$

Comment: There is no such $F$ in any elementary topos, if I am not mistaken this then is also not possible in Zermelo, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე there is such an *injective* $F$ that is an isomorphism. This is taken from a model of Zermelo set theory that admits an external automorphism that shifts ordinals downwardly, in that model take $X$ to be some set $V_\alpha$ were $\alpha$ is non-standard ordinal [where $F(\alpha) < \alpha$], take the restriction of that automorphism to $V_{\alpha+1}$, then we get our $F$.

Comment: Here is an argument adapted from Johnstone's "Sketches of an Elephant", D.4.1, Proposition 4.1.8(i) (page 948). It is in fact the standard Russell paradox kind of argument. I believe it does not use anything beyond Zermelo. In fact it does not even use tertium non datur. Let $$R:=\{F(Y)\mid Y\subseteq X \& F(Y)\notin Y\},$$and suppose $F(R)\in R$. This means that $F(R)=F(Y)$ for some $Y\subseteq X$ with $F(Y)\notin Y$. But since $F$ is injective, $F(R)=F(Y)$ implies $R=Y$, so $F(R)\notin R$. This in turn implies that $F(R)\ne F(Y)$ for any $Y\subseteq X$ with $F(Y)\notin Y$, so $F(R)\ne F(R)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, how did you prove the existence of $R$ in the above system? I believe you freely used $F$ in instances of separation, which is forbidden! (notice the note in brackets next to separation, the symbol $F$ is not a symbol of the language of set theory)

Comment: I took the complement of $\in_X\subseteq X\times\mathcal P(X)$ in $X\times\mathcal P(X)$, then took the image of this complement under the map $\operatorname{identity}_X\times F:X\times\mathcal P(X)\to X\times X$ and then intersected this image with the image of the diagonal $X\hookrightarrow X\times X$. Did I use anything forbidden?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე what is $\in_X $? also how did you define the map $\operatorname{identity}_X\times F$?

Comment: $\in_X$ is $\{(x,Y)\mid x\in X \& Y\subseteq X \& x\in Y\}$. The map is the one sending $(x,Y)$ to $(x,F(Y))$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე how do you prove the existence of this map? I still believe one needs to use $F$ in instances of separation, which is forbidden.

Comment: You do have the map $F:\mathcal P(X)\to X$, don't you? You then have $G\times F$ for any existing map $G$, including the identity map.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, no $F$ is NOT a set! It is an *external* function. If $F$ was a set, then we cannot forbid it from being used in separation.

Comment: I see, thanks, I must be more careful. But your forward copying allows to form $F$-images of any $m\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$, right?

Comment: @the axiom about $F$ is to be read as: $\forall a,b: F(a)=F(b) \implies a=b \land \\ \exists X: \forall Y \subset X \exists z \in X (F(Y)=z)$

Comment: OK, let me make sure I understand the rest correctly. Namely I think that your Forward copying means that I can form the image of any (definable in the system) $A\subseteq\mathcal P\mathcal P(X)$ under the map $\mathcal P\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(X)$ which sends $m\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ to its image under $F$, while Backward copying means that I can form the image of any definable $A\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ under the map $F^{-1}:\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P\mathcal P(X)$. Am I right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I forgot to mention that $\forall Y \forall z(F(Y)=z \implies Y \subseteq X \land z \in X)$, in my prior comment. Now as for your last comment. Basically I think it's clearer if one think of 3 levels of *external* functions $``F,G,H"$, now $F$ is a map from $\mathcal P(X)$ to $X$ while its converse $F^{-1}$ is from $X$ to $\mathcal P(X)$. Now $G: \mathcal P \mathcal P(X) \to \mathcal P(X)$, while $H:\mathcal P \mathcal P \mathcal P (X) \to \mathcal P \mathcal P (X)$.

Comment: Now the map $G$ sends sets of subsets of $X$ to their $F$-set images (i.e. sets of all F images of their elements), while map $H$ sends sets of sets of subsets of $X$ to their $G$-set images. The forwards and backward axioms are about map $H$ and its converse.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე,just to avoid confusion, the converse of $F^-1$ has the range of $F$ as its domain, so $F^{-1}: Range(F) \to \mathcal P(X)$, I write this because $Range(F)$ can be a proper subset of $X$. The same apply to the converses of $G$ and $H$, they are maps from their ranges to their domains.

Comment: OK I deleted it for the time being. Still I find these ordinals in Zermelo quite obscure. It is not even clear to me why are there enough well-orderings to contain every set in some $V_\alpha$...

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, and I’m curious about the anonymous downvote — would the downvoter care to explain their reasoning?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, well the ordinal rank of $V_\alpha$ [that is $\alpha$] is a non-standard ordinal, one needs to dive deep into Mostowski's proof of those models of Zermelo that admits such rank shifting automorphisms. I don't have much knowledge at that level, however Mostowski's article is referenced in Holmes's article. I personally think that the ordinals in those models are transitive sets of transitive sets that have subclasses of them that are infinitely descending membership chains, I still think they don't have cyclic membership chains,

Comment: those subclasses of those ordinals are not seen inside the model, so the model thinks of those ordinals as von Neumann ordinals, i.e. well founded transitive sets of transitive sets [the usual von Neumann ordinals]. Anyhow, I'm not pretty much sure of that, this is my guess about the nature of those ordinals, definitely they are non-standard. So I think the models themselves are ill-founded models of Zermelo.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, yes the model can contain every *set* that would be interpreted as a set in NFU in the resulting model. They would be the elements of $V_\alpha$ that code subsets of $V_\alpha$, the elements of $V_\alpha$ that do not code subsets of $V_\alpha$ [i.e. those that are not $j$ ($F$ here) images of subsets of $V_\alpha$] would be seen as Ur-elements in the interpretation because the membership relation $x \in y$ restricts $y$ to be a code of a subset of $V_\alpha$. So definitely $V_\alpha$ all *sets* (in the above sense) can be elements of $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Is not there for example a model of Zermelo with no uncountable well-orders?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, you can have a model of Zermelo in which all von Neumann ordinals are (internally) countable definitely. But, even in those models there are well orderings that are (internally) uncountable, for example a well ordering on the set of all equivalence classes of well orderings over N under order isomorphism.